# How to map a complex JSON value to an array of simple objects

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following JSON which is returned by a webservice:

```
[{
    "Author": {
      "Title": "Luis Valencia"
    },
    "Editor": {
      "Title": "Luis Valencia"
    },
    "Id": 1,
    "ID": 1,
    "Title": "Generic List Item 1",
    "Modified": "2017-10-23T20:02:22Z",
    "Created": "2017-10-23T20:02:22Z"
  },
  {
    "Author": {
      "Title": "Luis Valencia"
    },
    "Editor": {
      "Title": "Luis Valencia"
    },
    "Id": 2,
    "ID": 2,
    "Title": "Generic List Item 2",
    "Modified": "2017-11-07T17:52:34Z",
    "Created": "2017-11-07T17:52:34Z"
  }
]
```

Using this code:

```
let items: IListItem[];
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
requester.get(
    `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "odata-version": ""
        }
    }
)
.then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
    return response.json() 
})
.then((json: { value: IListItem[] }) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
    return this._listItems = json.value;
  });
break;
```

How can convert the json.value to an Array of IListItem? that would be done in the THEN statement, but dont know how to.

Update 1
IListItem

```
export  interface IListItem {
    [key: string]: any;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    modified: Date;
    created: Date;
    modifiedby: string;
    createdby: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mapping the array you receive in your json to a new array of `IListItem` in the `.then` method as follows.

```
let items: IListItem[];
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
requester.get(
    `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    {
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "odata-version": ""
        }
    }
)
.then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: [] }> => {
    return response.json() 
})
.then((json: { value: [] }) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
    this.items=json.value.map((v,i)=>({ 
        key: v.id,
        id: v.id,
        title: v.Title,
        createdBy: v.Author.Title,
        ..... //other fields go here.
    })

  });
break;
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but here's a similar answer:

```
.then(json => {
    const items = [];
    for (const obj of json) {
        const listItem: IListItem = {
            id: String(obj.ID),
            title: obj.Title,
            modified: obj.Modified,
            created: obj.Created,
            modifiedby: obj.Editor.Title,
            createdby: obj.Author.Title
        }
        items.push(listItem);
    }
    return this._listItems = items;
})
```

see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76qaLadk/) also.

---

As a side note you could use two interfaces, one for the JSON objects you receive from your webservice and one for the objects you use in your API. Something like this:

```
interface IListSubItemJSON {
    title: string;
}

interface IListItemJSON {
    Author: IListSubItem;
    Editor: IListSubItem;
    ID: number;
    Title: string;
    Modified: Date;
    Created: Date;
}

interface IListItem {
    [key: string]: any;
    id: string;
    title: string;
    modified: Date;
    created: Date;
    modifiedby: string;
    createdby: string;
}

class ListItem implements IListItem {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    modified: Date;
    created: Date;
    modifiedby: string;
    createdby: string;

    private constructor(id ? : string, title ? : string, created ? : Date, modified ? : Date, createdby ? : string, modifiedby ? : string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.plantName = plantName;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public static createFromJSON(json: IListItemJSON): ListItem {
        return new ListItem(json.plantCode, json.plantName, json.version);
    }

    public static createFromJSONArray(json: IListItemJSON[]): ListItem[] {
        const items: ListItem[] = [];
        for (const item of json) {
            const listItem: ListItem = ListItem.createFromJSON(item);
            items.push(listItem);
        }
        return items;
    }

    public toJSON(): ListItemJSON {
        ...
        return new ListItemJSON(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

This way you no longer have a strong dependency on the webservice data structures in the sense that if they modify you only need to adapt your mappings.

Your 'then' code simplifies to:

```
.then(((json: {
    value: IListItemJSON[]
}):ListItem[]) => (this._listItems = ListItem.createFromJSONArray(json.value)));
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are expecting to get JSON back in the response, (i.e. setting the `Accept` header to `application/json`), but you are actually getting back XML. I wouldn't normally expect `request.json()` to attempt to coerce the XML to a plain javascript object.

You will need to implement some additional logic beyond `response.json()` to parse your response.

EDIT:

Assuming your sever can't be configured to actually return JSON, you will likely want to pull in an XML parsing library. Keep in mind XML cannot map directly to JSON; they are fundamentally different. This means you likely have to do some additional work than just passing your document to some library function. Without a more specific question the best I can do is point you to some resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-parser

Comment: that is exactly my question

Comment: Oh. I see. You meant the first `.then` block. I'll edit.

Comment: please see Update1, with this can you give a more precise answer?

Comment: I changed the title of the question to better ressemble the problem at hand